# Search for the first letter of a word using keyboard input in data grid view

Tags: c#, datagridview, selection

My question is how to search for a word's start with a letter which is given by  keyboard. I did this using the code below.

Now I want to do this for the next row. Once I find a word, I want to go to the next row by clicking the down arrow. But when I click the down arrow, the selected row goes to the previous selected row.

How can I solve this?

```
if (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar))
{
    if (Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (dgvTestHead.Rows.Count); i++)
        {
            if (dgvTestHead.Rows[i].Cells["Test_Head"].Value.ToString()
                .StartsWith(e.KeyChar.ToString(),
                            true,
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                dgvTestHead.ClearSelection();
                dgvTestHead.Rows[i].Cells[0].Selected = true;
                dgvTestHead.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = i;
                dgvTestHead.Refresh();

                return; // stop looping
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `RowFilter` property of a DataView to filter? http://techbystep.blogspot.com/2009/07/dynamic-searchingfiltering-of.html

Answer (score 1):

I think it happens because the `CurrentRow` property of the `DataGridView` doesn't change.
To set the `CurrentRow` to the selected row (it is read-only), use:

```
dgvTestHead.CurrentCell = dgvTestHead.Rows[i].Cells[0];
```

this worked for me.